# JKS creation with every certificate renewal through cert-manager using Let's encrypt as CA

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, devops, jks

We have a reporting application which needs JKS file to be created from public certificate and private key associated with the certificate.

For our K8S deployment through Jenkins, we create this application and during this application deployment - pods, svc, ing, certificate also gets created and once our deployment is successful we call another script to use the certificate and private key, create a JKS and copy it to the pod in some location where application can pick it up. This works well but how do we automate this JKS creation and copy it to the pod with every let's encrypt certificate renewal since the certificate is renewed for every 90 days.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any issues you faced? Consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok,so with our application deployment we are deploying ingress resource as well and this where virtual host routing and TLS termination happens and prior to all this cert-manager is already installed with clusterissuer. Now, as soon as cluster issuer sees the ingress resource it reads the TLS section and cert-manager creates the certificate for the respective domain. In our case we are creating certificate for each and every ingress we are deploying in the cluster. Please check next comment since system is not allowing more characters

Comment: Once we have the public certificate and private key,we are calling the below script for JKS creation.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash`   
`kubectl get secret "xxx" -n ${INSTANCE_NAME} -o go-template='{{index .data "tls.crt" | base64decode }}' > tls.crt`  
`kubectl get secret "xxx" -n ${INSTANCE_NAME} -o go-template='{{index .data "tls.key" | base64decode }}' > tls.key`  
`openssl pkcs12 -export -in tls.crt -inkey tls.key -out newcert.p12 -password pass:xxx`   
`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore newcert.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias 1 -srcstorepass secret -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks -deststorepass xxx -destalias spring -noprompt`

Comment: `pod_name=$(kubectl get pod -n ${INSTANCE_NAME} | awk 'FNR == 2 {print $1}')`  
`kubectl cp ${WORKSPACE}/orbit-deployer/keystore.jks -n ${INSTANCE_NAME} ${pod_name}:/appdata/certs/saml`

Comment: Please update your question with this details. Thank you for answer, and now you want someone to automate it for you? Or what is the issue you're facing?

Comment: ok,ignore all of previous comments.Does,cert-manager support on demand certificate renewal?

Comment: Yes, it does. See [here](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/cmctl/#renew)

Comment: @moonkotte that helped...Thanks!! I just to need to check if cert manager does the change public(which is the actual certificate) and private key when it renewals the certificate

Comment: Have you managed to move forward? Any questions so far?

Comment: What exactly worked? You can [post your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), but it has to be detailed so it will be useful for community.

Comment: Ok,to be more specific like I said our application needs a JKS file which has to be a file not a K8S secret for our application to use and JKS has to be created from the certificate and private key which was created by clusterissuer and since our CA is let's encrypt it does renew the certificate in every 90 days and it can do it in the night 3:00am also,so to on demand renewing the certificate "crictl" command helped and we can create a JKS when client is not accessing the application

Comment: Are you talking about `cmctl` which I shared above? CLI for certificate manager? [this](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/cmctl/). `crictl` is a different tool and used for controlling container runtimes

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer from comments.

---

After some comments, main question was narrowed down to:

**"How to renew certificate manually using `CertManager`?"**

---

**Answer itself:**

There's a CLI tool for `CertManager` which is called [`cmctl`](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/cmctl/).

And it supports [manual renewal of certificates](https://cert-manager.io/docs/usage/cmctl/#renew) by issuing following command:

```
cmctl renew $CERT_NAME
```